# Lock dependencies by secure checksum in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, checksum

When I distribute a source project with a POM I can define dependencies with version strings. The build will download those dependencies if they are not in the local repository, it will even verify the checksums of those downloaded files with the metadata from the same repository (`-C`).

However the build will download those dependencies from a number of public repositories (and proxies) and my users are at the mercy of those public services if they will return unmodified files.

I would like to have a way to record the checksums of all my build dependencies and ship them together with the POM (so I am sure the files are unaltered but I dont need to ship a copy of my local repository to builders).

Is there a Maven way to do this? Similiar to that, is there a easy way to archive my dependencies (copy of the local repository with all used artifacts and metadata files) so I can repeat my build even when the central repositories fail or ship them to offline customers?

(Both without the need for an repository proxy if possible. I know I can build something to do that, I just wonder if there is a infrastructure in maven for that already. Maybe shipping a local repository which does only contain the metadata files or similiar?)

NB: I am not looking for `createChecksum` on the generated artifacts, but on locking the checksums of the used dependencies. I found a [`maven-create-checksums`](http://nicoulaj.github.io/checksum-maven-plugin/examples/generating-project-dependencies-checksums.html) plugin, but no corresponding verifyer.

Comment: Sonatype requires a GPG signature on every artifact uploaded into Maven Central. Maven does not check this signature, because checking it is a selling feature of the commercial flavor of their Nexus repository manager. The connection between your commercial Nexus instance and your build machine is assumed safe (and, admittedly, easy to secure).

Comment: Thanks @Barend, but this does not help me if I want to distribute to a wider audience (who probably not even have own repository servers)

Comment: I know it's not helpful, that's why I didn't post it as an answer :-/. It does explain why the GPG checksum situation is the way it is.

Comment: Thanks Barend, I guess I should have a look into writing plugins :)

Comment: The checksum check is also in Nexus OSS btw.

Comment: How is the trust relation to the expected checksum (or gpg key) established? When I created my sonatype OSS account for my artifacts, I was never asked for the used openPG key for the artifact group. What happens if I hand over one of my projects to someone else, who starts uploading the artifacts with a different openPG key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [BitcoinjEnforcerRules](https://github.com/gary-rowe/BitcoinjEnforcerRules), which appears to be an plugin for Maven's [enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) (that's right it's a plugin for a plugin). It works similar to [gradle-witness](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/gradle-witness), which means it compares the checksum of (hopefully) *all* used artifact dependencies to a list you have previously created.

While it's better then nothing, an ideal solution would be if one could simply set the checksum (or the openPG key used to sign the POM in case it's an snapshot artifact) for the POM of direct dependencies, and the POM of those dependencies would contain the checksum of it's artifacts, and the checksum (/openPG key, if snapshot) of the POM of its direct dependencies, and so on.
Note that if checksums are used, then they should be tied to a particular maven repository, since the same (non-changing, i.e. non-snapshot) artifact may have different checksums in different repositories.